# Laravel: Can I cache a query and then display results with jquery/javascript based on time and user key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, caching

I want to trigger a flash message when a specific event (row) in a query satisfies two criteria:

1. The time ('PropTime') is within 5 minutes of expiring
2. The user ('userID') is associated with the row

Rather than querying the database constantly for each user, I would like to produce a global query every hour that lists all upcoming events (with PropTime and userID) and cache it (using Laravel's built in 'Remember()' method), then search this list of results (with jquery or javascript) for qualifying events every 3 seconds or so (and trigger a flash message).

But I am not sure how to access the cached results with jquery/javascript nor how to write the script - or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll do something like this. The Laravel side:

```
Route::get('events/query', function() {

    // Get the events that belong to the User
    // where the PropTime is less than 5 minutes away
    // and cache the returned events for 1 hour
    $events = \Cache::remember('events', 60, function() {
        return \App\Event::where('PropTime', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)
            ->where('userID', \Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
    });

    return response()->json($events);

});
```

The JS/jQuery side (using jQuery for $.ajax):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/events/query',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // log the data so you can see how to
        // get what parts you want with JS
        console.log(data);

        // loop through the events
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // the event name
            console.log(data[i].name);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but on the Laravel side I want to load events regardless of when they expire (or maybe load those that expire in the next hour) and then do the filtering on time on the JS/jQuery side (what happens next in my app is that the user has a five minute window to take action). If I run the query in your way I would have to repeat it with high frequency across all users - that's what I want to avoid (I want to limit to either one global query that I then filter for user/time or a user-specific query that I filter for time).